# Older objects groups get removed from Scene when adding a new group three.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I'm working on a visual components designer, one functionality is to Group objects under a name, where a red box should be drawn around grouped objects when any of them is selected.

ISSUE:
when adding the red box as a LineSegments object to the scene (or any kind of object for that matter), the original objects get removed from the scene, I'm sure that I'm not removing them in any other part of my code.

The code is really long but I will share the related snippets.

**Creating the wireframe**

```
export const createGroupBoundingBox = (group: Group, gName: string): Group => {
  const newGroup = new Group();
  const box3 = new Box3();

  box3.setFromObject(group);
  // make a BoxBufferGeometry of the same size as Box3
  const dimensions = new Vector3().subVectors(box3.max, box3.min);

  const planeGeometry = new PlaneGeometry(
    dimensions.x + BoundingBoxMargin,
    dimensions.y + BoundingBoxMargin
  );
  // move new mesh center so it's aligned with the original object
  const matrix = new Matrix4().setPosition(
    dimensions.addVectors(box3.min, box3.max).multiplyScalar(0.5)
  );
  planeGeometry.applyMatrix4(matrix);
  // make a mesh
  const mesh = new Mesh(planeGeometry, new MeshBasicMaterial());
  // wireframe
  const geo = new EdgesGeometry(mesh.geometry);
  const wireframe = new LineSegments(
    geo,
    new LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, linewidth: 5.0, side: DoubleSide })
  );
  wireframe.position.setZ(ZIndexForBoundingBox); // not working
  const txt = getText(
    gName.toUpperCase(),
    planeGeometry.attributes.position.array[0],
    planeGeometry.attributes.position.array[1]
  );

  newGroup.add(wireframe);
  newGroup.add(txt);
  newGroup.userData = {
    objectType: ObjectType.boundingBox,
    info: {
      uuid: group.uuid,
      linePoints: dimensions,
    } as unknown as BoundingBoxRef,
  } as unknown as ObjectRef;

  return newGroup;
};
```

**Adding the wireframe to the scene**

```
const bbox = createGroupBoundingBox(g, newGroup.name);
scene.add(bbox);
```

[image: Before grouping]

[image: After grouping]

Comment: Simplify the problem with a basic scene, and try to replicate the problem. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Sometimes simplifying the problem exposes the cracks in the more complex version. At the very least, it will allow us to debug your code easier.

Comment: Thanks, @TheJim01, the problem was adding the objects that belong to different groups to one single new group in order to create the bounding box, these objects were attached to the scene with their original groups, and when they were added to a different group (that is not present in the scene) they get detached from the scene and disappear, the solution was to clone the objects without modifying the originals, and then calculate the bounding box according to the cloned ones. thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

the problem was adding the objects that belong to different groups to one single new group in order to create the bounding box, these objects were attached to the scene with their original groups, and when they were added to a different group (that is not present in the scene) they get detached from the scene and disappear, the solution was to clone the objects without modifying the originals, and then calculate the bounding box according to the cloned ones. thanks for the advice!
here is the code to clone the objects:

```
const objsClone = objects.map((obj) => obj.clone());
```

for your reference, THREE.js allows you to natively clone objects without having to create your own code to do so.